# Leaflet subdomains: if subdomain is down, attempt another

Tags: leaflet

When giving leaflet an array of subdomains for a tile layer, how can I cause it to try a different subdomain if the attempted subdomain is down?

For instance, adding this layer:

```js
var map = L.map( 'map', {
    center: [20.0, 5.0],
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: 2
});

L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright" title="OpenStreetMap" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" title="MapQuest" target="_blank">MapQuest</a> <img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png" width="16" height="16">',
    subdomains: ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4','otile5','otile6']
}).addTo( map );
```

This causes some of the tiles to fail to load because subdomains `otile5` and `oltile6` don't exist.

[image]

Of course in this case, I would just not include the `oltile5` and `oltile6` subdomains (because they don't exist): but what if, hypothetically, `otile1` was down? Perhaps because the service is unreliable. Does Leaflet handle this case by attempting another subdomain? If not, is it possible to get Leaflet to switch subdomains if it encounters an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what if, hypothetically, otile1 was down?

If one subdomain is down, then they are all down. Let me quote from https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_servers:

> Generally several subdomains (server names) are provided to get around
>   browser limitations on the number of simultaneous HTTP connections to
>   each host. Browser-based applications can thus request multiple tiles
>   from multiple subdomains faster than from one subdomain. For example,
>   OSM, OpenCycleMap and CloudMade servers have three subdomains (a.tile,
>   b.tile, c.tile), MapQuest has four (otile1, otile2, otile3, otile4),
>   all pointing to the same CDN.

You're not really hitting different servers - you're hitting the same server several times by referring to it in several different ways.

Comment: Is this true universally, or just for these services?

Comment: It's *generally* true for most services. You can check yourself by resolving the DNS names of all the tileservers aliases.

Comment: Right. The subtext for this question is however that we're considering providing our own subdomains for one of our tile services that don't resolve to the same underlying server. So still interested in seeing if map clients can handle this.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to consider [Leaflet.FunctionalTileLayer](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#tile-load), or a custom tile loading plugin. While it's certainly possible, I don't think that it has been implemented (yet).